# how to solve error EXC_BAD_ACCESS in my application?

Tags: iphone, ios4, ios-simulator

I am loading the custom cell on tableView and i return 50 rows in the tableView.
number of some rows are display in the tableview but when scroll the tableview my customcell is not display and I have the error

> "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"

and also display following message on the console

> "void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation*): delegate (webViewDidLayout:) failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: UITrackingRunLoopMode"

Comment: It would help a lot if you included some code. What EXC_BAD_ACCESS means, is basically that you tried to access some memory you weren't allowed to (generally going out of bounds in an array or accessing an object through a pointer after it's deleted). The rest of the error message doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

Comment: Hi I have similar issue ..please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374844

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you get this error due to your method of making custom cells. When you made the class file for the custom cell in the .m file you released the IBOutlets. Try removing that portion from your code than try.

I had the same problem in an app, and I solved that problem this way. Maybe this solution will work for you too.

Comment: Hi I have similar issue ..please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374844

Answer (score 2):

The best way to detect zombies is:

1. in the **Groups and Files** section,
   expand the **Executables** section
   and right click on your app name and
   choose **Get Info**
2. select the **Arguments** tab on the top and then add a new entry in the **Variables** to be set in the environment section. Name the new variable to **NSZombieEnabled** and set its value to **YES**.

After this you will have information in console on which released objects you make calls.

Answer (score 1):

This typically means that you have asked the program to look at a memory area that you don't have access to, which usually means you have run off the end of an array, or something.

If you are running in debug mode, the stack trace will probably give you more clues. Open up the debug console.

Answer (score 0):

You should also use [NSZombieEnabled](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled), it usually helps. It shows you which deallocated object was accessed. Be sure to disable it after you use it because using this, no memory is ever released.